# Dealing with auto-created indexes when changing columns in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have inherited a schema that has a table with a few cols that are varchar(max). They are used frequently to filter and it is very clear that we should create indexes on these cols (they need to be in the key; not in the includes). Sizing down will take a while, I get that. What I am concerned with is that my predecessor turned on the auto create index option, so I don't know what indexes are out there, meaning I don't know what indexes to drop across out 140+ client databases. I'm afraid that if we just deploy a script to reduce the size, we will run into a violation/error about changing a column that an index relies on.

I have created a script that finds what indexes are out there with the column and then drop it before proceeding with the col size reduction. Seems like there should be a better way to deal with column alters when there may be Azure-created indexes out there. Is there?

Thanks

Edited to Add: The columns were originally created as varchar(max). What I am saying is that was inappropriate, as the values in the columns are *at most* 50 characters. They are indeed good candidates for indexes. I have been able to test this out on our development environment, which I can much more closely control/it's easier to know what indexes exist. The crux of my problem is dealing with the indexes that may have been created with these in the includes column via the auto-create.

Comment: If they are a `varchar(MAX)` then they aren't a good candidate for an `INDEX`. The definition of the column is stating it's likely to be *over* 8,000 bytes in size and *could* be up to *2 Gigabytes* in size; you can't index a value that wide. You might want to have a look at full text indexes instead.

Comment: If the columns are being used for searches, e.g. `where HugeString like '%paisley%'`, then an index won't be of much use. A table _scan_, or possibly index _scan_, will occur with every row being checked. A _starting with_ match, e.g. `HugeString like 'paisley%'` with no initial wildcard, can benefit from an index _seek_. Note that full-text indexes have other issues, e.g. ignoring _noise words_ and numbers, matching different forms of a word, ..., that may or may not be beneficial in your environment.

Comment: Are you saying that the columns were declared as `varchar(max)` but they should have been declared as something much shorter and you want to make them shorter and index them? If they were `varchar(max)` Azure can't have created them as key columns in an auto tuning created index - though I guess they may be included columns. What is your desired result here? Just drop any auto created indexes or leave them?

Comment: TBH If you have 140 client databases supposedly in the same state but with adhoc differences you should probably start by collating all such differences from your baseline to see where you stand though and then plan from there

Comment: @martinsmith Yes, I am saying that they were originally declared as MAX but really should have been varchar(50). I added my clarification to the original question. The part about the includes is specifically what I am concerned about. I honestly would like to just drop them and create my own filtered indexes that I have planned out. I'm just not sure if there's a better way to handle the indexing outside of the script I have written. I am confident that will work, it just feels janky.

Comment: Well if you just want to set the schema to a known level and unceremoniously drop any extra indexes probably a dcapac publish could do this and figure out the differences and drop script needed